# Point dev URL to the default folder of a multisite

Tags: multi-sites

In a **multisite set up**, the default domain [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) point to the 'sites/default' folder.

I want a **temporary subdomain point to the default site for development**.

In the **sites.php** files I have:

$sites['dev.domain.com'] = 'default'; // this line can be removed due to the default behavior (see comment below)

$sites['sub1.domain.com'] = 'sub1.domain.com';

$sites['sub2.domain.com'] = 'sub2.domain.com';

$sites['sub3.domain.com'] = 'sub3.domain.com';

**Pointing to the 'default' folder is not working for some reason?**
What is wrong?

Comment: The default behaviour if the domain isn't listed in sites.php is to go to the default site. If dev.domain.com isn't taking you to default then which site does it take you to? Sounds like there's more to this and you've got other things happening

Comment: @Leigh Yes, there is a misconfiguration in the DNS settings. That is why it was not working indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above settings are correct. But there was an error in the DNS settings.